# Error: Unable to find a template file within the VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I'm trying to upload a new version of my Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) to the Visual Studio Marketplace (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/).
After uploading the new .vsix file, I get the following error:
"Error: Unable to find a template file within the VSIX." 
The extension works properly when I install it manually in Visual Studio 2015.
I uploaded the previous VSIX version about 11 months ago.
Does anyone know what this message means? 
What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue.
It looks like my template indeed included a path to a directory which didn't exist. This template was identical to the template I released 11 months earlier, so it looks like the Visual Studio Marketplace performs additional validations which didn't exist before.